# asyncio and aiohttp "Cannot connect to host"

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a piece of code which checks whether domains from a list host a website or not.

I'm running 100 parallel tasks which consume the domains from a queue.

The issue I'm facing is that I get false negative errors `Cannot connect to host` on some domains, while the same domains may actually produce valid `200` HTTP response when processed individually using the exact same code.

Here's a cleaned-up version of the code I use to do the actual call:

```
def get_session():
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=False, family=socket.AF_INET, resolver=aiohttp.AsyncResolver(timeout=5))
    return aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector)

async def ping(url, session):
    result = PingResult()

    try:
        async with session.get(url, timeout=timeout, headers=headers) as r:
            result.status_code = r.status
            result.redirect = r.headers['location'] if 'location' in r.headers else None
    except BaseException as e:
        result.exception = classify_exception(e)
    return result
```

When it's called, it gets the session returned by `get_session()` as a parameter (all tasks share the same session, I tried it with one session / url, didn't work):

```
async with get_session() as session:
    await ping(url, session)
```

(`PingResult` and `classify_exception`, `headers`, `timeout` are defined outside).

I'm using `uvloop` and `aiodns`, and running it on Ubuntu 18.04.

Is there a reason why this code should run fine when executed alone, but sometimes fail with `Cannot connect to host` when ran in multiple tasks?

Comment: Have you tried with amount of parallel tasks? Does it happens with 50 concurrent tasks?

Comment: Yes, it happens with 50 concurrent tasks as well. What also happens is that it gets time-outs for sites that otherwise work, and that return 200 when checked individually.